# From awk output, how to cut or trim characters in columns

Tags: bash, awk, cut

#### At the moment

I want to trim `.fmbi1a5nn9sp5o4qy3eyazeq5.eddvrl9sa8t448pb38vibj8ef:` and `.ilwio0k43fgqt4jqzyfadx19v:` so the output take less space :)

First step:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}: {{.Status}}" | sort -k1 | column -t

mon_node-exporter.fmbi1a5nn9sp5o4qy3eyazeq5.eddvrl9sa8t448pb38vibj8ef:     Up  7      days
mon_prometheus.1.ilwio0k43fgqt4jqzyfadx19v:                                Up  7      days
```

#### I know

I can do something like:

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}: {{.Status}}" | sort -k1 | rev | cut -d"." -f2- | rev

mon_node-exporter.fmbi1a5nn9sp5o4qy3eyazeq5
mon_prometheus.1
```

#### The issue

is that I'm losing the other columns :-/

#### Idea

It would sound logical to do something like this (with awk) but it does not work. Any ideas?

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}} : {{.Status}}" | sort -k1 | awk '{(print $1 | rev | cut -d"." -f2- | rev),$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' | column -t
```

Thank you in advance!
P

Answer (score 0):

to cut the last dot extension

```
$ docker ... | sort | awk '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$1)}1' file | column -t

mon_node-exporter.fmbi1a5nn9sp5o4qy3eyazeq5  Up  7  days
mon_prometheus.1                             Up  7  days
```

or, delete anything longer than 20 chars after a dot.

```
$ ... | sed -e 's/\(\.[a-z0-9:]\{20,\}\)* / /' | column -t

mon_node-exporter  Up  7  days
mon_prometheus.1   Up  7  days
```

Answer (score 0):

Works! This trick will make my life so much easier.

*(I removed file)*

```
docker ps --format "{{.Names}}: {{.Status}}" | sort -k1 | awk '{sub(/\.[^.]*$/,"",$1)}1' | column -t;

mon_grafana.1                                   Up  24  hours
mon_node-exporter.fmbi1a5nn9sp5o4qy3eyazeq5     Up  23  hours
```

**Question #2**:
Now how would you proceed to cut the characters after the first dot?

Cheers!